# Conditional running if some replicates exist

Tags: r

I have a list of files named in this way:

```
Myexpdate1_R1.txt        
Myexpdate1_R2.txt     
Myexpdate1_R3.txt       
Myexpdate2_R1.txt     
Myexpdate2_R2.txt       
Myexpdate2_R3.txt
```

How can I ask R to run a pipeline only for experiments for which the three replicates are available and not for the others? In other words if the case is the following:

```
Myexpdate1_R2.txt     
Myexpdate1_R3.txt       
Myexpdate2_R1.txt     
Myexpdate2_R2.txt       
Myexpdate2_R3.txt
```

the code will not run for Myexpdate1 because Myexpdate1_R1.txt is not available but it will run for Myexpdate1_R2.txt because all the three replicates are available. I tried by dividing the length of `list.files()` of files containing the pattern `*R[1-3].txt` by 3 in order to run if it returns an integer and not to run otherwise but unfortunately I experienced troubles during the proper identification of integers by R.

Comment: It is not clear.  Perhaps `sapply(split(files, sub("_.*", "", files)), function(x) length(unique(x)))==3` or may be `lapply(split(files, sub("_.*", "", files)), function(x) if(length(unique(x)))  lapply(x, read.table, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))`

Comment: Did you mean "if some **files** exist", in the title ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you start with a list of filenames `flist`,
this should give you a d.f. with a `execute` column set to `0` if you miss an "R" in one experiment, `1` otherwise. For example:

```
flist <- c("Myexpdate1_R1.txt", "Myexpdate1_R2.txt", "Myexpdate1_R3.txt",       
           "Myexpdate2_R1.txt", "Myexpdate2_R2.txt") 

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
flist <- c("Myexpdate1_R1.txt", "Myexpdate1_R2.txt", "Myexpdate1_R3.txt",       
           "Myexpdate2_R1.txt", "Myexpdate2_R2.txt") 

exec <-  flist %>% 
  str_split_fixed("_",2) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(replicas = str_split_fixed(V2, ".txt",2)[,1]) %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(execute = ifelse (n() == 3, 1, 0))

> exec
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Experiment execute
       <chr>   <dbl>
1 Myexpdate1       1
2 Myexpdate2       0
```

You can then use `exec` to decide if running or not the simulation. For example with a simple `for` loop:

```
names(exec)[1] <- "Experiment"
for (exp in seq(along = exec$Experiment)){

  if (exec[exp,]$execute == 1){
    message("Experiment:", exec[exp,]$Experiment,"--> OK, RUN")
    print("DOING SOMETHING")
  } else{
    message("Experiment:", exec[exp,]$Experiment,"--> FAIL")
    print("DOING NOTHING")

    }
}
```

> Experiment:Myexpdate1--> OK, RUN
>   "DOING SOMETHING"
>   Experiment:Myexpdate2--> FAIL
>   "DOING NOTHING"

Comment: just edited to borrow the shorter "pattern check" from @akrun

Comment: Hi LoBu. I tried to run the piece of code you suggested to me, but if I want  to add a new condition, i.e. the pipeline will run only on Myexpdate2 for which I have three replicates, and not on Myexpdate1 how I have to modify the code you wrote?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I don't get it. What is the further condition you want to add ?

Comment: In the current way my pipeline works only if there are 3 replicates of Myexpdate1 and Myexpdate2 (these are only two examples). It does not work completely although Myexpdate2 has 3 replicates. I only would like to run the pipeline on experiments that have 3 replicates (Myexpdate2 in this case) and not on experiments that have less than 3 replicates. This is an added requirement to my original question.

Comment: Got it. From your original question, it seemed that the condition was to run only if ALL experiments had three replicates. You just have to remove the last line of the pipe. That way, you'll have a df with one for experiments with three replicas, 0 otherwise. You can use that to decide which  experiments to run. If you updated the question, I'll update the answee.

Comment: Ok ok you are right. This an additional requirement. The original question was to run only if all the replicates per experiment were available. I' m modifying the question.